# apt-get returns 100 when bitbaking meta-toolchain-qt5

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto, bitbake

I'm rebuilding `meta-toolchain-qt5` after an update of the Yocto SDK provided by the vendor (ST). This time and the end of the compilation I an error 100 from `apt-get`. Here the full log:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function sstate_task_prefunc
DEBUG: Python function sstate_task_prefunc finished
DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.28.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.65.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_8.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/mklibs/mklibs-native_0.1.43.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/apt/apt-native_1.2.24.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.24.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_8.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:nativesdk:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc-locale_2.28.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:nativesdk:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/qemu/qemuwrapper-cross_1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/prelink/prelink_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/qemu/qemuwrapper-cross_1.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-extended/xz/xz_5.2.4.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/glibc/cross-localedef-native_2.28.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['glibc', 'quilt-native', 'gcc-cross-arm', 'mklibs-native', 'apt-native', 'dpkg-native', 'gcc-runtime', 'nativesdk-glibc-locale', 'nativesdk-qemuwrapper-cross', 'prelink-native', 'qemuwrapper-cross', 'pseudo-native', 'xz-native', 'cross-localedef-native', 'opkg-utils-native', 'qemu-native', 'systemd-systemctl-native', 'depmodwrapper-cross', 'kmod-native', 'debianutils-native', 'openssl-native', 'elfutils-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'libtool-native', 'binutils-native', 'autoconf-native', 'automake-native', 'shadow-native', 'update-rc.d-native', 'linux-libc-headers', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'mpfr-native', 'flex-native', 'binutils-cross-arm', 'gmp-native', 'zlib-native', 'libmpc-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'curl-native', 'gettext-native', 'db-native', 'pkgconfig-native', 'bzip2-native', 'perl-native', 'libgcc', 'nss-native', 'chrpath-native', 'alsa-lib-native', 'glib-2.0-native', 'dtc-native', 'pixman-native', 'libsdl2-native', 'gtk-doc-native', 'python3-native', 'm4-native', 'gdbm-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'nspr-native', 'libpcre-native', 'libffi-native', 'util-linux-native', 'libpng-native', 'util-macros-native', 'libx11-native', 'libxrender-native', 'libxrandr-native', 'libxext-native', 'readline-native', 'lzo-native', 'ncurses-native', 'xtrans-native', 'libxcb-native', 'xorgproto-native', 'libxau-native', 'libxdmcp-native', 'libpthread-stubs-native', 'xcb-proto-native']
DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_populate_sdk
NOTE: Initializing intercept dir for /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/st/stm32mp1/2.6-snapshot/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi
DEBUG: Collected intercepts:
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/delay_to_first_boot
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/postinst_intercept
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_font_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_gio_module_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_gtk_immodules_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_icon_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_pixbuf_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_udev_hwdb

NOTE: Initializing intercept dir for /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image
DEBUG: Collected intercepts:
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/delay_to_first_boot
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/postinst_intercept
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_font_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_gio_module_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_gtk_immodules_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_icon_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_pixbuf_cache
  /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/openembedded-core/scripts/postinst-intercepts/update_udev_hwdb

NOTE: Installing TARGET packages
NOTE: Executing 'cd /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo/sdk-provides-dummy-nativesdk; PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages;/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/hosttools/gzip -fcn Packages > Packages.gz;PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive release . >> Release' ...
NOTE: Executing 'cd /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo/x86_64-nativesdk; PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages;/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/hosttools/gzip -fcn Packages > Packages.gz;PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive release . >> Release' ...
NOTE: Executing 'cd /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo/stm32mp1; PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages;/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/hosttools/gzip -fcn Packages > Packages.gz;PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive release . >> Release' ...
NOTE: Executing 'cd /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4; PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages;/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/hosttools/gzip -fcn Packages > Packages.gz;PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive release . >> Release' ...
NOTE: Executing 'cd /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo/all; PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages;/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/hosttools/gzip -fcn Packages > Packages.gz;PSEUDO_UNLOAD=1 /local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-ftparchive release . >> Release' ...
NOTE: Installing the following packages: bash-dev packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target
ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command '/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/build-openstlinuxeglfs-stm32mp1/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/apt-get  install --force-yes --allow-unauthenticated bash-dev packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target' returned 100:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Package packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target' has no installation candidate

DEBUG: Python function do_populate_sdk finished
ERROR: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
```

I guess the key is here:

> Package packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target is not available

How can I retrieve information about *why* it's not available?
These directories exist:

```
buildhistory/packages/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target
tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target/1.0-r0/deploy-debs/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4
```

But I'm not able to understand if the content is correct.

### UPDATE

```
$ bitbake packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target -c do_deploy

ERROR: Task do_deploy does not exist for target packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target (/local/STM32MP15-Ecosystem-v1.1.0/Distribution-Package/openstlinux-4.19-thud-mp1-19-10-09/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/packagegroups/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bb:do_deploy)
ERROR: Command execution failed: 1

$ ls tmp-glibc/deploy/deb/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target-d*
tmp-glibc/deploy/deb/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target-dbg_1.0-r0.0_armhf.deb
tmp-glibc/deploy/deb/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target-dev_1.0-r0.0_armhf.deb
```

Comment: IIRC, it's important that the .deb packages exist in the shared state output directory, which I think is in the deploy directory (`tmp/deploy/debs`). `do_deploy` should generate the `.deb` package in `workdir/deploy-debs` and then the shared-state-cache machinery should copy it to tmpdir/deploy/deps and store it internally aswell. If you removed the debs from `tmpdir/deploy/debs`, I think you need to re-execute `bitbake packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target -c do_deploy`. IIRC, this should "materialize" the deb-files into `tmpdir/deploy/debs` out of the shared-state-cache.

Comment: I'll try as soon as possible but I didn't removed anything. I just `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` as usuale.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb question updated

Comment: I'm out of ideas. it was just a shot in the blue. still need to learn the yocto system. EDIT: apparently the correct task name is `do_package_write_deb`. you can also check `-c do_listtasks`

Comment: The last command completes successfully, but when I try do `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` again, nothing has changed.

Comment: The problem was the missing of `inherit packagegroup` in the related `.bb` file. I'm not sure how I removed it (inadvertently, of course). It's a fact that the error messages above didn't lead to this.